# In a Ubuntu release version, what kinds of updates/upgrades can we (not) get on installed packages and Linux kernel?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, kernel, debian, versions

In Debian Stable, although I haven't experienced it, I heard that the versions of installed packages and kernel can be increased. I am not sure in what sense that means. A version number usually consists of three fields. I guess it might mean we can't update or upgrade an installed package or Linux kernel in the first field, but only in in the last two fields.

In a Ubuntu LTS (e.g. Lubuntu 18.04), what kinds of updates/upgrades can we get on installed packages and Linux kernel? What kinds can't we get? In this aspect, which one is it more similar to: Debian Stable, Testing or Unstable?

In a Ubuntu non-LTS version, similar questions.
In this aspect, which one is it more similar to: Debian Stable, Testing or Unstable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  My current Ubuntu 19.04 is closest to debian-testing; myself I don't think there is a debian-unstable equivalent (though having -proposed enabled would be closest).  As for stable releases 18.04 LTS is closest to debian stable (but usually a year out in release), 16.04 LTS to debian old-stable etc.  Debian has no equivalent to non-LTS releases.

Comment: I am mainly asking about in a Ubuntu release (LTS or not), how much can I update/upgrade an installed application (and Linux kernel) along the development of the application (and Linux kernel), without reinstalling a newer Ubuntu release.

Comment: In that regard they are pretty much the same.  Both use release models, ie. a release is done at a set time with the near-latest packages available at release-time, with only security fixes backported to the release (ie. it's not later packages/programs, the same packages will remain but with later security-fixes backported to them, the prime exceptions to this is when backporting fixes is more effort than just upgrading to a later release of a package). This applies to both debian & ubuntu. If you want the latest release packags, you use Ubuntu non-LTS & upgrade every 6-9 months.

Comment: As for kernels - that's what HWE (hardware enablement stack) is about.  18.04 LTS with HWE enabled will be using the 18.10 kernel, and then jump to 19.04 kernel (on release), then 19.10 and finally bump to 20.04 LTS kernel. It's useful where you need the latest kernel for additional hardware functionality on newer devices & are willing to lose a fraction of stability to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

My currently used Ubuntu 19.04 is closest to debian-testing.

Myself, I don't think there is a debian-unstable equivalent (*though having -proposed enabled on my 19.04 would be closest*).

As for stable releases 18.04 LTS is closest to debian stable (but usually a year out in release, for example debian-9 release was june-2017, debian-8 was april-2015, debian-7 was may-2013, so it's not a fixed month but odd-year)

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to debian old-stable
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is debian old-old-stable

Ubuntu LTS has the HWE kernel option; Debian has no easy switch to enable something like this.  Most other updates are rather similar between Ubuntu and Debian in my opinion.

Debian has no equivalent to non-LTS releases (they release only about every second year, and have no intermediate releases).

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu versioning environment is targeting what I'd call stability. So once you install a given version (18.04), the software installed on that version is nearly only getting upgraded with patches to prevent crashes and any security issues. Anything else doesn't change (i.e. no new features).

So for example if I create a package version 1.0.0 of libfoo, I clearly state that the 3rd version number is for patches only. You may see updates on your machine such as 1.0.1, 1.0.2, etc. but you will never see 1.1.0 or 1.1.3... because 1.1.x is going to have changes that could generate huge problems. The issue being that you have many software for a given version and for stability to remain high, you can't take the risk of changing anything that could impact one of the other 10,000 packages.

In most cases, though, Ubuntu versions in such circumstances change in a different manner. A version can include dashes and letters and it is often that a version will have `-ubuntu<number>` at the end. This is because many package owners do not really follow the patch vs upgrade numbering scheme that Debian/Ubuntu would like you to follow (I know I don't, it's very difficult to do in practice especially when you're working by yourself on a project).

As for an equivalent with Debian, I've never used Debian so I don't really have much clue. guiverc's answer is probably the closest it would get to answer that part of your question.

### But I'd like the latest of Bar package...

Since 16.04 (maybe a bit earlier?) we had Snap. A new system which creates a form of `chroot` environment. This is very similar to what Microsoft has been offering for a while. This environment can make use of the main libraries and also have its own set of libraries to run your software. This is useful to make sure things run for that one software.

Since 18.04, I think that this environment works pretty well. So if you want a stable system but have a few software on the edge (i.e. the Chrome browser), then use the Snap version of those few software.